# SQL query (in indicator) for talend DQ

Tags: sql, talend, analysis

In Talend Open Studio for Data Quality, User defined indicators, Can we write an sql query involving 2 tables?

This is the scenario, I have 2 tables :

1. dbo.test, having column dept.
2. dbo.role, having column dept.

The following query is used to extract those records from dbo.test, whose dept values are not in  dbo.role.

```
Use [BigData]select dept from dbo.test 
where dept not in (Select dept from dbo.role).
```

While executing, it gives the following error:

```
An exception stack trace is not available.
```

How do I resolve this and what is the correct approach to write this query ?

Comment: Downvotes should be followed by an explanation comment. I don't see any particular reason for the downvote

Answer (score 0):

I think it will better for you to create a view by writing your query

(select dept from dbo.test where dept not in (Select dept from dbo.role)) 
in database

and then use that view in talend component as table :)